# Sending integer values in response from node js server

Tags: java, android, node.js

I have a node js server implementation and I would like to send some values to an Android (Java) client. The method of the node js server is as follows:

```
app.get('/GetValues*', function (request, response) {
    // Request needs to be a GET
    if (request.method == 'GET') {

        var username = request.query.account;
        var time_now = Date.now();

        var db = database('./database.db'); 
        var row_account = db.prepare('SELECT SCORE score, STARTED_STUDY_SERVER_MILLIS timestamp, DAYS_TOTAL days_total FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE NAME = ?').get(username);

        var score = row_account.score;
        var days_total = row_account.days_total;
        var days_count = time_now - row_account.timestamp;
        var minutes_count = time_now - row_account.timestamp;

        var statement = db.prepare("UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET DAYS_COUNT = ?, MINUTES_COUNT = ? WHERE ID = ?");
        statement.run(days_count,minutes_count,getAccountID(db, request.query.account));

        var row_usage = db.prepare('SELECT DURATION_ENABLED duration_enabled, DURATION_DISABLED duration_disabled FROM USAGE WHERE NAME = ?').get(username);
        var duration_enabled = row_usage.duration_enabled;
        var duration_disabled = row_usage.duration_disabled;
    }
});
```

I would like to send the values `score` (integer), `days_total` (integer), `days_count` (integer), `minutes_count` (long), `duration_enabled`  (long), `duration_disabled`  (long) to the client.

How can I send it to the client? I think response.send() only accepts strings. How can I parse the values in Java when received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to send all those values at once, it's common to respond with a JSON in such a case. In express, you can send a JSON response using [`response.send()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) or [`response.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) like this:

```
app.get('/GetValues*', function (request, response) {
  // ... your db operations here, then
  response.json({
    score: score,
    days_total: days_total,
    days_count: days_count,
    minutes_count: minutes_count,
    duration_enabled: duration_enabled,
    duration_disabled: duration_disabled
  });
});
```

This will send a response with `Content-Type: application/json` and a JSON string in the body looking like this:

```
{"score":12,"days_total":12,"days_count":12,"minutes_count":12,"duration_enabled":12,"duration_disabled":12}
```

Then you just [parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2591098/5045563) in your Java code.

---

By the way, this line

```
if (request.method == 'GET') {
```

is unnecessary. Registering a handler via `app.get()`, express will only handle `GET` requests anyway.